# padx on Tkinter Frame in python produces different spacing on different machines

Tags: python, tkinter

Are there any factors that would cause the padx option of a Tkinter Frame to result in different sizes on different screens/OS? I am developing on Linux and I have a set of icons lined up using the padx option. When another user on a Windows machine tried it, the icons are out of place.

Please let me know if there is any other relevant information I can provide.

Comment: Provide a [Minimal, Complete, Valid Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)—some runnable code, and maybe a screenshot of the differences on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Meanwhile, are you using styled Tk or traditional Tk? (If you post your code, this will be obvious…)

Comment: Yes, I am going back through the code and trying to pinpoint the exact problem. I will post code once I narrow it down. Part of the problem is that I am not using Tk directly, but a layer on top of Tk created for our particular software.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic with `padx` -- it specifies an absolute number of pixels for padding. A value of one means one pixel on every window manager on every OS. There must be more to your problem than simply padding.

On different window managers or OS's, however, the default borderwidth on widgets may be different, and there are other defaults that may be different from platform to platform.

Comment: I was hoping for magic. :/ I am going back through everything right now. I will post more info as I uncover it.